# Merge 'battery-life' with 'battery-usage'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I'm trying to figure out the difference between [battery-life](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) (x122) and [battery-usage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-usage) (x16). From the questions using the tags, they seem pretty similar -- so it's not that *battery-life* stands for the over-all lifetime of the battery, while *battery-usage* applies to the charging cycle.

Should we merge `battery-usage` into `battery-life` and make the former a synonym to the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done, I agree with your assessment.